# If I register two different directives with the same name in two modules, will the last registration win?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, if I register two different directives with the same name in two modules, will the last registration win? IIUC Angular modules provide no namespacing.

Also, do modules in Angular provide anything other than a convenient grouping of configuration of the injector?

Put another way - can you detect at runtime which module something (say a directive) came from?

Edit: re the first part of this question: I think it will. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Test it and find out.

Comment: 1) 2 directive with the same name will *BOTH* be applied; this is surprising, but has uses when you want to augment the functionality of a built-in directive. You can `require` the controller of the other directive. 2) angular modules offer just that - not much of use IMO

Comment: no namespacing ? Well just names properly, like angular did prefix all his directive's name with ng, which make a prefix `ng-` on the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AngularJS, if I register two different directives with the same name
>   in two modules, will the last registration win?

It will be a 'tie'. Both of them are registered and both of them are executed. The execution order for directives with the same `priority` is the same as the order in which they were defined, and `link` functions will be executed in reverse order.

If they don't meet certain conditions, i.e.

> - Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.
> - Multiple directives publishing a controller under the same name.
> - Multiple directives declared with the transclusion option.
> - Multiple directives attempting to define a template or templateURL.

...then a [respective error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir) is thrown. Note that the documentation is inaccurate on 'isolated scope', it is 'new scope' in fact, both simultaneous `scope: true` and `scope: { ... }` are prohibited. One scope max per element.

> Put another way - can you detect at runtime which module something
>   (say a directive) came from?

No, not without hacking Angular. But `multidir` error will tell you module names if there are directive collisions.