# Nested and sibling Angular applications in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*First: I understand this is a nasty hack and that Angular was never intended to be used this way. I am exploring nested AngularJS apps  in the knowledge that this is an abuse of the framework until my organisation moves to more modern tech like Angular2 and library-based functionality.*

I have created [a proof of concept demonstrating the use of nested and sibling AngularJS applications](https://jsfiddle.net/benaston/o22bxnbf/27/).

There are two buttons: "Add App" and "Remove App".

When "Add App" is clicked AngularJS is configured for the new application, which is then bootstrapped against an in-memory DOM node, and then injected into the DOM. Lots of sibling applications can be injected into the DOM in this way.

When "Remove App" is clicked the last application to be added is destroyed along with its DOM.

What I don't fully grok is how this works, given that if I add an app, remove it, and then add it again, I get no conflicts of any kind, even though the module name being used is the same each time (the module name corresponds to the index of the application in the `apps` array).

Specifically: the `angular` object on the global object is being reconfigured via the `module` API repeatedly and I might expect this to cause a problem.

Can someone help me understand why this works (or if indeed it really doesn't)?

Comment: i see no imediate problem on that approach. indeed, manual bootstrap is quite well documented: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization and the use of multiple small modules are said to be a good practice: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#many-small-self-contained-modules IMO the dynamic approach, if well defined and self-contained have no debt with any other documented technique... except to get documented too ;-)

Comment: Thanks. What are the pitfalls associated with having the inner apps nested inside the outer app? Are there risks of conflicts or unexpected sided effects?

Comment: What does confuse you here? The fact that sub-app's root element is detached from DOM at the moment when `bootstrap()` is called allows to evade [this safety mechanism](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/Angular.js#L1667-L1674). Sub-apps are bootstrapped here similarly to how it is done in unit tests. The example doesn't explain why it can't be a single app with lazy loading and namespaced directives (namespacing is a must if you have conflicting names). Registered sub-app modules won't go away and will stay in RAM.

Comment: This is the source of my confusion: there is only ever one `angular` object. IIUC, this `angular` object can be configured via the `module('module-name', [])` interface. My demo enables the repeated configuration of the `angular` object with AngularJS modules of the same name, with directives of the same name. I was expecting a conflict. Presumably it is simply overwriting the previous configuration?

Comment: The directive would be appended (not overridden) to `my-directive` selector if only these modules were connected somehow. However, modules have different names, they don't depend on each other, only one of these modules is used per each instance. If you will do `angular.module(\`app${i}\`, ['app0'])`, you will see that the modules start to interfere.

Comment: Thank you. If in my demo I press the "Add App" button, `app0` is configured and created. If I then press the "Remove App" button, then the DOM associated with this app is removed and the app is eligible for garbage collection (presumably). If I click "Add App" again, `app0` is configured and created a second time. This results in no conflicts. Presumably because the new `app0` module completely overwrites the old `app0` module?

Comment: Yep. The list of modules is internal object, they are just addressed by module names as keys. `angular.module(...)` is getter function. `angular.module(..., [])` is setter, it overrides the whole module.

Comment: Per your comment re module interference: in the example you provide, the modules would start to interfere. But the *applications* would not interfere, because IIUC the way the process works is that the injector is configured using the `angular` object at the time of injector instantiation and the modules registered with the `angular` object are not used again by an app after its bootstrap.

Comment: And finally: given that `angular.module(...,[])` is a setter, is it viable to therefore "wipe the slate clean" by enumerating all the modules registered with `angular` and setting them to an empty module, before requiring additional child applications to *completely* configure themselves to avoid module registration leakage between applications?

Comment: `angular.module(...,[])` is a setter for `...` name. It will wipe `...` module. It is not possible to wipe all modules (getter/setter pattern is there to secure that). Yes, the app instances won't interfere. But modules can. `angular.module(`app${i}`, ['app0'])` will cause compiler to throw because there are multiple directives with template per `my-directive` selector.