# creating simple directive in 2 different ways

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a very simple directive in 2 different ways . One using anonymous function (the traditional way) and other using named function. The named function is giving me following error--

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
```

Here is my code :

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", []);
// first way--working fine
angular.module("exampleApp")
  .directive("showProducts", function() {

    return function() {

      console.log('first');
    };

  });

// second way--not working fine
angular.module("exampleApp")
  .directive("showProducts", second())


function second() {
  return function() {

    console.log('second');
  };

};
```

```html
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
  <title>Directives</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      pls chk console-
      <show-products></show-products>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am unable to find the reason.

Comment: I have created the directive with same name twice. Which one angular will consider. I can see both is considered. Also why the second one is executing first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove **parenthesis** and make it like this :

```
    angular.module("exampleApp")
  .directive("showProducts", second) /* call the reference of the function here */


function second() {
  return function() {

    console.log('second');
  };

};
```

By the way if you register two directives, angularjs will consider them both. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702149/if-i-register-two-different-directives-with-the-same-name-in-two-modules-will-t).

Comment: Excellent! working fine. But I have created the directive with same name twice. Which one angular will consider. I can see both is considered. Also why the second one is executing first?

Comment: @DebnathChakraborty Yes both are considered ;) you may check this link for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702149/if-i-register-two-different-directives-with-the-same-name-in-two-modules-will-t

Answer (score 0):

You've got to give the reference of the named function, not to call it.

Change this: `.directive("showProducts", second());`

To this: `.directive("showProducts", second);`